# What does the '@' symbol do in Rust?

Tags: rust

I forgot to specify the type of a parameter and the error message was as follows:

```
error: expected one of `:` or `@`, found `)`
 --> src/main.rs:2:12
  |
2 | fn func(arg)
  |            ^ expected one of `:` or `@` here
```

Which raises the question: what can you do with an `@` symbol? I don't remember reading about using the `@` symbol for anything. I also did some Googling and couldn't find anything. What does `@` do?

Comment: There's [an entire appendix for all the symbols used in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/appendix-02-operators.html).

Comment: @Shepmaster whoa cool, thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the `@` symbol to bind a pattern to a name. As the [Rust Reference demonstrates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html):

```
let x = 1;

match x {
    e @ 1 ... 5 => println!("got a range element {}", e),
    _ => println!("anything"),
}
```

Assignments in Rust [allow pattern expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#let-statements) (provided they are complete) and [argument lists are no exception](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#function-parameters). In the specific case of `@`, this isn't very useful because you can already name the matched parameter. However, for completeness, here is an example which compiles:

```
enum MyEnum {
    TheOnlyCase(u8),
}

fn my_fn(x @ MyEnum::TheOnlyCase(_): MyEnum) {}
```

Comment: When I read [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/patterns.html#bindings), I think it finally clicked for me – but would I be correct in saying that pattern binding with `@` is shorthand for guards? E.g., `e if 1 <= e && e <= 5`? Not saying the shorthand wouldn't be helpful / possibly make the source clearer (assuming the syntax is understood) – I just want to make sure I'm not missing a use case of `@` in the spirit of "what can you do with the `@` symbol".

Comment: @SeanAllred That's certainly one way to look at it. In the examples I gave, you'd basically be correct. The only thing I'd mention is that patterns can be nested and `@` let's you bind different parts of a structure to various names: `a @ Some(p @ Point { x = 5, .. })` now `a` has type `Option<Point>` and `p` has type `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` symbol allows you to reuse a variable holding a value that's used simultaneously in a match pattern.

For example:

```
enum Student {
    Junior{ id: u32}
}

let me = Student::Junior{ id: 10 };

match me {
    Student::Junior{ id: id_val @ 0..=10 } => println!("in range with id: {}", id_val),
    Student::Junior{ id: 11..=20 } => println!("in range 11->20"),
    Student::Junior{ id } => println!("outside range with id: {}", id)
}
```

In this example, by binding `id` to the `id_val` the match can be used in the `println!()`, otherwise this won't be possible as seen in the second match expression.