# Why does a macro call inside another macro not expand, but instead I get "no rules expected the token `!`"?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, macros

I'm calling a macro within a macro, i.e

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    (yes) => {
        true
    };
    () => {
        false
    };
}

macro_rules! baz {
    () => {
        [(); 0]
    };
    ($args: tt) => {
        $args
    };
}

macro_rules! parse_rule {
    ($rule: tt, $args: tt, $newline: expr) => {
        println!("The rule is {}, with args {:?}", $rule, $args);
        if $newline {
            println!()
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! bar {
    ($($rule: tt  $([$($args: tt),*])? $($flag: ident)?);+) => {
        $(parse_rule!($rule, baz!($([$($args),*])?), foo!($($flag)?)));+
    }
}

fn main() {
    bar!("hi" yes; "there" ["are", "some", "args"]; "no" yes);
}
```

The compiler complains about me calling `baz` within the `parse_rule` invocation:

```
error: no rules expected the token `!`
  --> src/main.rs:30:33
   |
19 | macro_rules! parse_rule {
   | ----------------------- when calling this macro
...
30 |         $(parse_rule!($rule, baz!($([$($args),*])?), foo!($($flag)?)));+
   |                                 ^ no rules expected this token in macro call
...
35 |     bar!("hi" yes; "there" ["are", "some", "args"]; "no" yes);
   |     ---------------------------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Why does it not expand?

Answer (score 5):

Macros are are invoked with their unexpanded arguments. `macro_call!(arg)` is **three** token trees, not one:

```rust
macro_rules! example {
    ($($x:tt)+) => {
        $(eprintln!(">{}<", stringify!($x));)*
    }
}

fn main() {
    example!(macro_call!(arg));
}
```

```
>macro_call<
>!<
>(arg)<
```

Your macro only allows for a single token tree (`$args: tt`). That matches the macro's name, leaving the `!`. That isn't matched by anything, so you get your error.

You probably want `$args: expr`.

> is there a way to expand it before? I want to parse some of the elements of the array manually

There's no "more eager" expansion, that I know of. It has been suggested in various RFCs (e.g. [Eager Macro Expansion — 2320](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2320)).

I'd suggest reflowing your code such that `parse_rule` calls `foo` / `bar` itself, or baking the logic of `foo` / `bar` directly into `parse_rule`. Internal rules are quite common for this.

See also:

- [What does an @ symbol mean in a Rust declarative macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54406388/155423)

Comment: Thanks, in that case is there a way to expand it before? I want to parse some of the elements of the array manually.

Comment: @lolad there's no "more eager" expansion, no. Perhaps reflowing your code such that `parse_rule` calls `foo` / `bar` would work, or baking that logic directly into `parse_rule`. Internal rules are quite common for this ([What does an @ symbol mean in a Rust declarative macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54406388/155423)).